# Oracle Trigger Never Fires

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have the following tables.

```
create table Surveys ( 
    survey_id int, 
    cid int, 
    num_submitted int, 
    sum_q1 int, 
    sum_q2 int, 
    sum_q3 int, 
    sum_q4 int,
    constraint pk_survey primary key (survey_id),
    constraint fk_courses foreign key (cid) 
        references Courses(cid)
);

create table Surveydata ( 
    survey_id int,  
    sid int,
    submit_time date,
    q1 int, 
    q2 int, 
    q3 int, 
    q4 int, 
    q5_str varchar(250),
    constraint pk_survey_data primary key (survey_id, sid),
    constraint fk_sdata_surveys foreign key (survey_id) 
        references Surveys(survey_id),
    constraint fk_sdata_students foreign key (sid) 
        references Students(sid)
);
```

And the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER survey_data_trigger
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON SURVEYDATA
    FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN
        IF INSERTING THEN
            UPDATE Surveys SET
                num_submitted = num_submitted + 1, 
                sum_q1 = sum_q1 + :new.q1,
                sum_q2 = sum_q2 + :new.q2,
                sum_q3 = sum_q3 + :new.q3,
                sum_q4 = sum_q4 + :new.q4
            WHERE
                survey_id = :new.survey_id;
        END IF;

        IF UPDATING THEN
            IF(:new.survey_id = :old.survey_id) THEN
                UPDATE Surveys SET
                    sum_q1 = sum_q1 - :old.q1 + :new.q1,
                    sum_q2 = sum_q2 - :old.q2 + :new.q2,
                    sum_q3 = sum_q3 - :old.q3 + :new.q3,
                    sum_q4 = sum_q4 - :old.q4 + :new.q4
                WHERE
                    survey_id = :new.survey_id;
            ELSE
                UPDATE Surveys SET
                    num_submitted = num_submitted + 1, 
                    sum_q1 = sum_q1 + :new.q1,
                    sum_q2 = sum_q2 + :new.q2,
                    sum_q3 = sum_q3 + :new.q3,
                    sum_q4 = sum_q4 + :new.q4
                WHERE
                    survey_id = :new.survey_id; 

                UPDATE Surveys SET
                    num_submitted = num_submitted - 1, 
                    sum_q1 = sum_q1 - :old.q1,
                    sum_q2 = sum_q2 - :old.q2,
                    sum_q3 = sum_q3 - :old.q3,
                    sum_q4 = sum_q4 - :old.q4
                WHERE
                    survey_id = :old.survey_id;
                END IF;

        END IF;

        IF DELETING THEN
            UPDATE Surveys SET
                num_submitted = num_submitted - 1, 
                sum_q1 = sum_q1 - :old.q1,
                sum_q2 = sum_q2 - :old.q2,
                sum_q3 = sum_q3 - :old.q3,
                sum_q4 = sum_q4 - :old.q4
            WHERE
                survey_id = :old.survey_id;
        END IF;
    END;
/
```

When I issue,

```
INSERT INTO Surveydata VALUES(1, 1, SYSDATE, 5, 5, 5, 5, 'Great teacher!');
```

the trigger doesn't fire and update the Survey record that this Surveydata record points to.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did the trigger compile successfully, and is it enabled? (You can check in `user_objects` and `user_triggers`)

Comment: What are the values of `num_submitted` and `sum_q1`, ... , `sum_q4` in the Surveys table before the `INSERT INTO Surveydata`, and what are they afterwards?

Comment: [Seems to work as expected](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d45e/1), assuming you start off with non-null values, which may be what Luke is hinting at (I guess?).

Comment: @AlexPoole the trigger compiled and installed successfully.  There's an entry for it in user_objects and user_triggers.

Comment: @Luke Woodward the values in Surveys are all set to 0 both before and after the insert.

Comment: That's odd.  The values in the Survey record don't change in the environment that I'm running this in after issuing the insert into Surveydata.

Comment: How are you checking - are you querying `surveys` in the same session that you do the insert; and if not, have you comitted the `surveydata` insert?

Comment: @AlexPoole: yes, that's what I was hinting at, as that's the first thing I did attempting to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've tried querying surveys in the same session and a new session.  I am committing after inserting into surveys too.

Comment: I have no idea what the difference is in my environment that's preventing this trigger from working like it does in the sqlfiddle.  I'm just learning Oracle.  Thank you both for trying

Comment: It turns out that the trigger wasn't actually enabled.  It was successfully created, but for some reason wasn't enabled upon creation.  @AlexPoole, since you had asked whether it was enabled, if you'd like to submit an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Have to tried it with 'before' trigger rather than 'after'. 'After' triggers fire on commit, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger will only fire if it is valid - that is, it was created without errors and hasn't since been invalidated in way that stops it recompiling successfully - and is enabled. You can  check the validity in the `user_objects` table:

```
select status
from user_objects
where object_type = 'TRIGGER' and object_name = 'SURVEY_DATA_TRIGGER';
```

If that says the trigger is `INVALID` you can see what errors it has in the `user_errors` table:

```
select text
from user_errors
where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'SURVEY_DATA_TRIGGER'
order by sequence;
```

... and then recreate it with corrected code. But since [this trigger seems to work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d45e/1), it is presumably valid for you and therefore is disabled, which you can check with:

```
select status
from user_triggers
where trigger_name = 'SURVEY_DATA_TRIGGER';
```

If that says it is `DISABLED`, you can enable it with:

```
alter trigger survey_data_trigger enable;
```

Your trigger creation code does not create it as disabled though, so if it is in that state, presumably you have another step which explicitly disables it. I can't think of anything that will automatically disable a new trigger* unless you have a DDL trigger that is changing the status on all newly created triggers, but you'd probably know about that, and you could test it quite easily. It seems more likely that you're disabling it yourself.

<sub>* well, there is a hidden init parameter, `_system_trig_enabled`, which would make it be created as disabled, but having that set seems rather unlikely too.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure why it was disabled on creation.  The trigger was for a class project and running on an instance of Oracle managed by my University.  The alter trigger statement did the trick.  Thanks again for your help Alex.